# Do not change ActiveAdmin locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, activeadmin

I'm using Rails 4 with ActiveAdmin.
Here is my application controller to detect user's locale:

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || 
                extract_locale_from_accept_language_header || 
                I18n.default_locale
end

# adds current locale to each url
def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end

def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  locale = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
  locale if ['uk', 'en', 'ru'].include? locale.to_s
end
```

This works great for user interface, but it also changes ActiveAdmin translation.
How can I keep English locale for ActiveAdmin?
I suppose something like `I18n.locale = :en if ActiveAdmin` should be user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the idea.

For instance, if you use devise with a separate model for AdminUsers and Users, you can do something like

```
if current_admin_user
   I18n.locale = :en #or better: default_locale
else
   #Your logic
end
```

If both admin and user are the same model, with a flag to differentiate them, add a is_admin method to your model returning true false with whatever flag you want and go for:

```
if current_user.is_admin?
   I18n.locale = :en #or better: default_locale
else
   #Your logic
end
```

Another way, maybe simpler, is to use the fact that ActiveAdmin controllers are namespaced so you can do in your ApplicationController something along:

```
if self.kind_of? ActiveAdmin::BaseController
   I18n.locale = :en
else
 #Your logic
end
```

Cheers.

Comment: Alredy tried first solution, but it looks than current_admin_user is aviable in user`s pages too. But second solution works great, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!